# Writing a simple class in C++

Tags: c++, class, private

I am getting an error saying that I can't access private members x and y. How do I write the methods getX() and getY() so that they could see x and y? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Point {
public:
    Point(int x, int y);
    Point();
    int getX();
    int getY();

private:
    int x, y;
};


int Point::getX() {
    return x;
}

int Point::getY() {
    return y;
}

void main () {

    Point p(5,5);
    Point g;

    cout << p.x << endl;
    cout << g.y;
    string s;
    cin >> s;

}
```

Comment: Your also missing the constructor definitions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um, you already *have* written `getX` and `getY`, you just need to use them:

```
cout << p.getX() << endl;
cout << g.getY();
```

---

Note that, because `getX()` and `getY()` don't modify your class, they should be `const`:

```
class Point {
public:
    // ...

    int getX() const;
    int getY() const;

    // ...
};

// ...

int Point::getX() const {
    return x;
}

int Point::getY() const {
    return y;
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be

```
cout << p.getX() << endl;
cout << g.getY();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access x and y, as they're private.  However, you've made getX and getY public, so your code would look like this:

```
cout << p.getX() << endl;
cout << g.getY();
string s;
cin >> s;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Point::getX()` and `Point::getY()` actually see `x` respectively `y` - the error is in your `main`, where you try to access them directly, without using the getters you made exactly for this purpose.

```
cout << p.getX() << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've solved the problem of writing the functions yourself.  Now all you have to do is change your `main` to call those functions:

```
// note the proper return type
int main() {
   Point p(5,5);
   cout << p.getX() << endl;
   // more code
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `get_` methods are correct. The problem is that you are not using them in your `main` function! Try this:

```
cout << p.getX() << endl;
```